# Chemical "article" about addictive nature of oxygen

Tags: story-identification

I recall reading something that ascribed itself to be from a peer reviewed journal, perhaps Journal of the American Chemical Society, though it also might have claimed to be from Scientific American or some not peer reviewed magazine. I did not read it in this format, I read it somewhere else probably online.

It was an "article" describing the addictive nature of oxygen to humans. Describing how a person becomes addicted within the first breath after birth, and remains so for their entire lives. And should a person be deprived, there are immediate and rapidly fatal withdrawal symptoms.

Searching for this I find lots of real research on the effects of oxygen on various addictions. These aren't what I read, the one I'm thinking of was obviously parody.

I apologize if this stretches the definition of science fiction too thin, the science part seems reasonable, I see the fictional part in that it was clearly a fictional article being paraded as peer reviewed. Though please close if I'm being, excessively, absurd.

Comment: I'll wait and see what others have to say before voting to close this, but my initial instinct is that this doesn't qualify as science fiction. There are lots of fictional stories involving science that we wouldn't count as science fiction, since none of the science involved is beyond real world science. This seems to to me to fall in the same area, but as I said, I'll wait to see what others think before voting to close this.

Comment: It has a bit of an Asimov smell to it, like his Thiotimoline "articles". Or the whole Dihydrogen Monoxide gag that circulated years ago. Was the article it's own thing, like a short story, or a part of a novel? If you read it online, it could have just been a cheeky forum post or something. I'd say if you can narrow that down it would probably help a lot.

Comment: The dangers of Dihydrogen Monxide are a gag or was it only years ago that it was a gag??? :)

Comment: @Vanguard3000 I do recall it having the air of an article, or an excerpt from an article. In that it didn't seem to be part of a larger story. May well have been a forum post where I read it, my interest is more in was it actually published in whatever it claimed to have been published in. Which if it was a random post, probably wasn't.

Comment: And yes, very much so in the line of DHMO

Comment: @FreeMan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihydrogen_monoxide_parody

I mean, technically the dangers of DHMO aren't a gag...

Comment: Well... if we're getting pedantic, @Vanguard3000, you could gag on DHMO...

Comment: I remember something similar about "bread" and "water" addiciton...

Comment: This question does not appear to be about science fiction or fantasy within the scope defined in [the Help Center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help).